# Replacing CASE in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I got three columns with binary values. Then i got a query which makes a string based on those values. I made this work using `case`. But it's quite huge (it's a part of a bigger query), and i was wondering maybe there is a better way of doing this?

```
SELECT (CASE
    WHEN TableA.flag1 = 1 AND TableA.flag2 = 1 AND TableA.flag3 = 1 THEN 'CGR'
    WHEN TableA.flag1 = 1 AND TableA.flag2 = 1 THEN 'CG'
    WHEN TableA.flag1 = 1 AND TableA.flag3 = 1 THEN 'CR'
    WHEN TableA.flag2 = 1 AND TableA.flag3 = 1 THEN 'GR'
    WHEN TableA.flag1 = 1 THEN 'C'
    WHEN TableA.flag2 = 1 THEN 'G'
    WHEN TableA.flag3 = 1 THEN 'R'
    ELSE 'nothing'
END)
FROM TableA
```

Im working on MSSQL 2000 server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `left()` instead.

```
select left('C', T.flag1)+
       left('G', T.flag2)+
       left('R', T.flag3)
from TableA as T
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is "better" but it is more concise:

```
SELECT ((CASE WHEN TableA.flag1 = 1 THEN 'C' ELSE '' END) +
        (CASE WHEN TableA.flag2 = 1 THEN 'G' ELSE '' END) +
        (CASE WHEN TableA.flag3 = 1 THEN 'R' ELSE '' END)
       )
FROM TableA;
```

Okay, this isn't exactly the same because you get `''` instead of `'nothing'`.  But I think the empty string does a better job of representing "no flags" than `'nothing'` does.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN flag1 = 1 THEN 'C' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN flag2 = 1 THEN 'G' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN flag3 = 1 THEN 'R' ELSE '' END
FROM TABLEA
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use function and move this CASE statement to this function